# Angularfire2, mergin data from two endpoints

Tags: rxjs, angularfire2

Hello and thanks in advance,

I have 2 end points in my firebase

1: /projects (holds a list of projects)

2: /project-attachments/{projectID} (returns all attachments for 'projectID)

I can't figure how to efficiently merge the project-attachments data to the project.

I would technically like to end up with an array of projects, and each project with its attachments

```
[
  {
      name : 'Project 1',
      attachments : [
        { 
          name : 'Attachment 1 name',
          value: 'value 1'
        },
        { 
          name : 'Attachment 2 name',
          value: 'value 2'
        }
      ]
  },

  {
      name : 'Project 2',
      attachments : [
        attachment-key1 : { 
          name : 'Attachment name',
          value: 'value 1'
        },
        attachment-key2 : { 
          name : 'Attachment name',
          value: 'value 2'
        }
      ]
  }

]
```

I have tried various rxjs operators like combineLatest or mergeMap etc. but I end up doing a lot of looping withing the operators which seems like overkill.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get do a join in angularfire2 database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755579/how-to-get-do-a-join-in-angularfire2-database)

Comment: @cartant thanks for the linked post, it was of great help.