# How to get details from angularFire Database and set it into a template

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to get a user details from a `angularFire2 database`. Therefore instead of using the `FirebaseListObservable`, I am using `FirebaseObjectObservable` since I am expecting just a user from the path.

This is the path and the colums through which I am deriving the user data

```
  path: /projects/users/
  columns: userID,username

  data
     userID:"001",
     username:"Icomin"
```

And this the `home.ts`

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { NavController,AlertController,ActionSheetController } from 'ionic-angular';
   import{AngularFireDatabase,FirebaseListObservable,FirebaseObjectObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';



@Component({
   selector: 'my-child-component',
   template: `<h1>Welcome {{ (projects | async)}}</h1>` // The template
})
export class HomePage{


projects: FirebaseObjectObservable <any>;

 constructor(af:AngularFireDatabase) {

      this.projects = af.object(`/projects/users`);
  }
```

I implement the template below, however the returns`Welcome [object object]`

The template implementation

```
 template: `<h1>Welcome {{ (projects | async)}}</h1>`
```

How do I get the user details from the above path and set it into the template

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755579/how-to-get-do-a-join-in-angularfire2-database

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am not joiing anything,  all I am trying to do is get details using the object observables

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Your code is reading `/projects/users`, which is a list of data. So your HTML will need to loop over that. Alternatively, make your code read a single user `/projects/users/user1`.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention , you get `Welcome [object object]` from projects variable. It's mean that you receive a list from this call `af.object('/projects/users')` .
I dont really know what exactly you want to do with that list but you few options:
1 - show all users in list :

```
template: ' <h1 *ngFor="let proj of projects | async">{{ proj.username }}</h1>
```

this will display all user's names , one by one.
2 - show specific user:
(you need to choose the filter criteria: userID or username)

```
export class HomePage{
  project: FirebaseObjectObservable <any>;
  constructor(af:AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.project = af.list(`/projects/users`,{
      query: {
          orderByChild: 'userID',      //or orderByChild: 'username',
          equalTo: <someUserID>        // equalTo: <someUsername>
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and then the template to display the current username:
    `template:  <h1>{{ project.username }}</h1>`

Hope it fits what you wanted.