# RxJs Compose a list of Observables and then combine (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm attempting to combine a list of observables, but haven't had luck with zip or other maps.

What I want to do is get a list of Genres for a given Artist Id. I'm using firebase, so it's a nosql database. I have a 'genresPerArtist' list that is a list of Artist keys, and each Artist key has a list of Genre keys. 
Structure:

```
    { 
         genresPerArtist: {
             artist1: {
                 genre1: true,
                 genre2: true,
                 genre3: true
            }
        },
         genres: {
             genre1: {
                name: 'Alternative'
             },
             genre2: {
                name: 'Jazz'
             } 
        }
    }
```

Here's the start of the function that I have:

```
getGenresByArtistId(artistId: string): Observable<any> {
     return this.db.list(`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`)
         .flatMap((genres: IDictionary[]) => {
             return genres.map(genre => this.db.list(`/genres/${genre.$key}`));
             // return Observable.zip(obvs);
         });
```

I'm not really sure what do do with the list that I get back from genresPerArtist. What I want to do, is take each genre.key (genre1, genre2, genre3), and use each one to fetch the value from 'genres'. I thought I could return a .zip, and then map over that, but I was not getting a response from zip.

Comment: WIth value of "genre" you mean the whole object associated to a genre key? Could you please specify the return type of the method? (Observable<any> ist helpful)

Comment: Yes, I figured that I would get the whole object associated with the genre key. I'll eventually just get the 'name' property from that.

Comment: Few elements should be array , you are showing all of them as objects

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41755911/6680611.

Comment: @cartant, thanks, forkJoin is what I needed, see the answer I posted. If you want to post an answer, you can and I'll mark is as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@cartant, thanks, that included what I needed, [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

```
// Compose an observable based on the genresPerArtist:
        return this.db.list(`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`)
        // Each time the genresPerArtist emits, switch to unsubscribe/ignore any pending user queries:
        .switchMap(genres => {
            // Map the genres to the array of observables that are to be joined.
            let genreObservables = genres.map(genre => this.db.object(`/genres/${genre.$key}`).first());
            return Observable.forkJoin(...genreObservables);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the following, asumming that the return of `genresPerArtist` returns a `Map<string, boolean>`:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import { zip } from 'rxjs/observable/zip';

getGenresByArtistId(artistId: string): Observable<Genre[]>{
   return this.db.list(`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`)
   .mergeMap((genres: Map<string, boolean>) => 
    zip(Array.from(genres.keys()).map(genre => this.db.list(`/genres/${genre}`))))
}
```

EDIT: Another option would be

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toArray';

getGenresByArtistId(artistId: string): Observable<Genre[]>{
       return this.db.list(`/genresPerArtist/${artistId}`)
       .mergeMap((genres: Map<string, boolean>) => Array.from(genres.keys())
       .mergeMap(genres=> genres)
       .mergeMap(genre => this.db.list(`/genres/${genre}`))
       .toArray();
    }
```

Basically Im flattening the results into a single array manually. I took the long way to make it easier to follow

Comment: It looks like mergeMap and flatMap are the same. The problem here is that if I subscribe to the emitted observable from getGenresByArtistId, it's never resolving. (It gets called, but never returns any items)

Comment: Yes, flatMap is an alias for mergeMap. Are you geting any errors? Is the first request (genresPerArtis) being sent?

Comment: No errors. Yes, /genresPerArtist gets sent and resolves, they array of Observables for each genre gets built as well. But when I subscribe to the final result, nothing resolves.

Comment: Good to know, lets try another variant

Comment: @mrshickadance any luck?

Comment: see the answer I just posted. forkJoin seems to be what I needed.